# For what value of $\alpha$ does this series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The Question is for what value of $\alpha$, does the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sqrt{n^\alpha + 1} - \sqrt{n^\alpha})$$

By setting $\alpha \leq 0$, we can show the series diverges by vanishing condition.

However, does $\alpha > 0$ guarantees the series converge? And why is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\sqrt{n^\alpha+1}-\sqrt{n^\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^\alpha+1}+\sqrt{n^\alpha}}\sim\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^\alpha}}$$
for sufficiently large $n$.

Now recall that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if and only if $p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{n^\alpha + 1} - \sqrt{n^\alpha} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^\alpha + 1} + \sqrt{n^\alpha}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^\alpha}}$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write $$A_n=\sqrt{n^\alpha+1}-\sqrt{n^\alpha}=\sqrt{n^\alpha}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^\alpha}}-1\Big)$$ So, assuming $\alpha>0$, for large values of $n$, consider that, by Taylor, $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ and then $$A_n=\frac 12\frac{1}{n^\alpha}-\frac 18\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}+\cdots$$